# image "zoom-out" appartion on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to write a script that would make an image appear on my page with a zoom out effect. I figured I could achieve that by changing the image's class. I wrote that, but it doesn't work at all (the image doesn't even load). 
Can you see where my mistake(s) is(are) ?

Here is the code :

HTML :

```
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Super titre</h1>
    <p>Paragraphe Paragraphe Paragraphe Paragraphe Paragraphe Paragraphe Paragraphe Paragraphe Paragraphe Paragraphe Paragraphe Paragraphe Paragraphe Paragraphe Paragraphe Paragraphe Paragraphe Paragraphe Paragraphe Paragraphe Paragraphe Paragraphe Paragraphe Paragraphe Paragraphe </p>
    <img id="monImage" onload="myFunction()" src="images/gear.png">
</div>

</body>
```

JS :

```
<script>
function myFunction() {

    $("#monImage").toggleClass("appeared");
})
```

CSS :

```
#monImage{
position: absolute;
height: 0;
width: 0;
z-index: 1;
}

#monImage.appeared{
width: 100%;
height:100%;
}
```

Thanks for the help !